# Take value from float number after dot

Tags: swift, swift2, swift-playground

How correctly extract second valued after coma in Float value.

Example:

```
var value = 5.435
```

And I would like to take value second value after coma, that is 3.

How to do this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this: `(int)( value * 100 ) % 10`.

Answer (score 3):

In case you want to handle both positive and negative values:

```
(Int)( abs(value) * 100 ) % 10
```

If you want to keep the sign, just remove `abs`

Comment: No need for the parenthesis around `Int`.

Comment: You're absolutely right, parenthesis around `Int` are not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

If its always going to be the third decimal, I would do it like this.

```
var value = 5.435
value *= 100

var digit = value % 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Mod is an expensive operation,  instead do

```
(Int(value * 100)) - (Int(value * 10) * 10)
```

In your scenario  we get

```
(Int(5.435 * 100)) - (Int(5.435 * 10) * 10);
(Int(543.5)) - (Int(54.35) * 10);
(543) - (54 * 10);
(543) - (540);
3
```

Comment: *"Mod is an expensive operation"* – more expensive than several multiplications plus rounding to an `Int`? Do you have any reference for this fact?

Comment: Here is a reference with embedded systems: http://embeddedgurus.com/stack-overflow/2011/02/efficient-c-tip-13-use-the-modulus-operator-with-caution/  It involves subtraction and division,  and unless the compiler is smart enough to switch your division to multiplication,  the division is also slow.  I just did a playground test,  looping 10000 times,  the mod takes about 2.8941 seconds,  my method takes 2.6752 on average.